Drop rows based on conditions (longitudinal dataset)
I have a dataset with the following structure:



ID
drug
drug sequence
drup type




A
X
1
AB


A
X
1
AB


A
Y
2
CD


A
Z
3
CD


A
V
4
EF


A
V
4
EF


B
W
1
GH


B
W
1
GH


B
W
2
GH


C
Z
1
CD


C
V
2
EF


C
V
2
EF



I want to keep only patients who are treated with CD & EF and exclude all other patients. The final result should be:



ID
drug
drug sequence
drup type




C
Z
1
CD


C
V
2
EF


C
V
2
EF



Patient A was excluded because even though it has been treated with both CD and EF it had been previously treated with AB.
I have tried things like:
df_group = df.groupby("id").filter(lambda x : (x["drug type"]=="CD").all())

But it is not working properly. I'd appreciate any feedback.

Just for clarity, you would exclude patients treated with only DC or EF, right?

@mozway I would keep patients only treated with CD and EF

@ReumaptSPR please have a look at the answer I shared, I guess it should give you the desired result by keeping the patients with CD and EF.

You may try to group the data by ID, check the unique drug type for each patient and ensure it contains only CD and EF, filter the groups where this condition is met. Return the filtered dataframe.

import pandas as pd

# Sample Data
data = {
    'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'drug': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'V', 'V', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'Z', 'V', 'V'],
    'drug sequence': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
    'drug type': ['AB', 'AB', 'CD', 'CD', 'EF', 'EF', 'GH', 'GH', 'GH', 'CD', 'EF', 'EF']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Filter the dataframe
def filter_patients(group):
    unique_drug_types = set(group['drug type'])
    return unique_drug_types == {'CD', 'EF'}

filtered_df = df.groupby('ID').filter(filter_patients)

# Display the result
print(filtered_df)


So, the result would be:
  ID drug  drug sequence drug type
9   C    Z              1        CD
10  C    V              2        EF
11  C    V              2        EF



You can use a set equality with groupby.transform and boolean indexing:
out = df[
    df.groupby('ID')['drug type'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == {'CD', 'EF'})
]

Output:
   ID drug  drug sequence drug type
9   C    Z              1        CD
10  C    V              2        EF
11  C    V              2        EF

Intermediate:
df.groupby('ID')['drug type'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == {'CD', 'EF'})

0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: drug type, dtype: bool


Something like that should work.
data = {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'drug': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'V', 'V', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'Z', 'V', 'V'],
        'drug sequence': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
        'drug type': ['AB', 'AB', 'CD', 'CD', 'EF', 'EF', 'GH', 'GH', 'GH', 'CD', 'EF', 'EF']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

patient_drugs = df.groupby('ID')['drug type'].unique()
valid_patients = patient_drugs[patient_drugs.apply(lambda x: set(x) == {'CD', 'EF'})].index
filtered_df = df[df['ID'].isin(valid_patients)]

print(filtered_df)

